# Is there a better alternative to this use of "puts" in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a class in a legacy project that looks like this:

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(user)
    unless Rails.env == "development"  # don't spam users when running legacy migrations
      begin
        UserMailer.welcome(user).deliver
        subscribe_user_to_new_account_mailinglist user
      rescue
        # THE FOLLOWING LINE IS THE ONE THAT BOTHERS ME
        puts "User##{user.id} - Signed up using an invalid email address."
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, there's that `puts` there. When I run our test suite, I get output like this:

```
be rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb
User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
...User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
..User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.User#1 - Signed up using an invalid email address.
.

Finished in 12.19 seconds
18 examples, 0 failures
```

I'm not a big fan of the extra clutter. Seems like I should only be seeing green dots.

What would be a better thing to do on that line instead of the `puts`?

Comment: What about `Rails.logger.info 'your message'`?

Comment: Rails.logger.debug "message"

Comment: That worked. If someone puts the `Rails.logger` thing as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In rescue you can use :-

```
flash[:error] = error.message "User##{user.id} - Signed up using an invalid email address."
```

this will also make the test green.